# Organization Name won't update in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

So, I'm in Google Cloud Platform, launching a Wordpress site and I Am at the stage of deploying.

I notice the billing account and organization details. The company changed names and I've updated all the company profile details with the new name. Thing is, Cloud Platform has not pulled this thorough. There is a helpful link to 'Edit in Google Admin console' at `Google Cloud Platform > Admin > [select organisation]`, hover over (wrong) org name then a settings box appears. In this settings box the link takes you to edit org details at G Admin console.

But, there are no more records I can update the name in.

So, my question is - why has this name changed failed to pull through from Google Admin console to the Google Cloud Platform? Is this permanent, written in stone or can this be corrected? Is so, how?[Image shows Cloud Platform settings with wrong org name and ID along with G Admin console details with correct name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBn7x.png)

We can't launch this project on Cloud Platform with the wrong company name!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Google, the Support Engineer came back after 48 hours and said I was imagining things.

Problem has been fixed by nice gremlins.

Not sure when Google rolled out this Organization feature on the Cloud Platform but I suspect this was a rectified glitch.

Alba gu bràth